# Giving background color only to one side of centered div

Tags: css

So, I have a menu which is inside a centered div. The centered div has a background color. Now I want to give the gap between the left browser window border and the centered div another color than the gap on the other side. I already tried a couple of methods like linear gradients or adding colored box with ::before, but nothing worked. [Here is a picture to visualize it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQdBY.jpg)

```
<style>
 .wrapper {
  width: 100%
 }

 .centered {
  margin: 0 auto
  max-width: 80em
  background-color: grey
 }
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="centered">
  <nav>Some menu...</nav>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: style="wrapper" ? You mean class="wrapper"

Comment: also `<div style="centered">` is wrong, you should write `<div class="centered">`

Comment: oh, thank you! sorry, I was still sleeping... :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) not 'style="wrapper"' but 'class="wrapper'
2) i would suggest to give the wrapper the background-color grey and the centered the background-color white:

```
<style>
 .wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 50%,#808080 50%,#808080 100%);
 }

 .centered {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 80em;
  background-color: white;
 }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="centered">
  <div>Some menu...</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know why :D, but this really works for me, thank you! Apparently I haven't still understood the magic behind gradients...

Comment: @WouterDenOuden had a similar approach including a very helpful link. Try the link, change the code till you understand it and you'll see there's no magic involved ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try out using an abrupt `linear-gradient` on the `.wrapper`, for example:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, red 5%, white 90%, gray 5%);
```

Just edit the percentages after the color to get the sizing.

Wrote you an example here. Simple and elegant.

http://jsbin.com/qivagowutu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: There are two problems with this solution:

1) When the browser window is really wide the gradient becomes visible
2) The 90% width prevents the navigation bar to be aligned with the main content

Comment: The 90% width was an example, your layout is fine as is. As for the gradient you can add more stops, e.g. red 10%, red 90%. And that way it would remain a gradient-less background between 10% to 90%

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to tool to make the right gradient:
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

for example:

```
background: #ff3232;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ff3232 0%, #ff2828 49%, #bed4e5 50%, #bed4e5 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ff3232 0%,#ff2828 49%,#bed4e5 50%,#bed4e5 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff3232 0%,#ff2828 49%,#bed4e5 50%,#bed4e5 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff3232', endColorstr='#bed4e5',GradientType=1 );
```

Maybe you already tried the right gradient, but you should change style="wrapper" to class="wrapper".

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/facundo_larocca/pen/pRzBob)

Now, inside your .centered you can put whatever you want, and even you can chose how much centered should use.

```html
<style>
 .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
 }

 .centered {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  flex: 1; 
 }

 .left-red {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 15%; 
 }
 .right {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 15%; 
 }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="left-red">
 </div>
 <div class="centered">
  <div>Some menu...</div>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
 </div>
</div>
```

***I've edited to add the left red background.***

### I strongly recommend you to read this [great tutorial about flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Let me know if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: I've edited my codepen to show you how you can sort them like you want. just change the % you want and you will not have to worry about sizes. Of course you can add another one on the right if you wish.

Comment: Hm, if you put an extra div with 15% the div.centered is not centered anymore

Comment: It's just an example, but it is going to be centered anyway, think about it. I've edited my answer to show you how it should look like

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but this is also not working, when the browser windows is really wide. The background color grey will re-appear on the left.

Comment: Jajaja, that's because you have set `max-width: 80em;`. I've edited again my codepen, take a look.

Comment: Please, read the tutorial I've suggested to you, [here it is](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: I know this tutorial already, but I can't see any solution with flex items. The max-width isn't there for no reason, it prevents the navigation from getting bigger than the content area.